# How to use multiprocessing with multiple arguments in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I had a for-loop that would take a URL from a set of URLs and reach out to that URL and do some other stuff, but it was taking forever, so I figured I'd speed it up with some multiprocessing, but am struggling to do so.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
def accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.starmap(processURL, zip(itertools.repeat(urlSet), user, verboseFlag))

def processURL(url, user, verboseFlag):
    filePath = some_path

    img_data = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(filePath, 'wb').write(img_data.content)


def main():
    ...
    accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag)
    ...
```

I get an error on the "pool.starmap(processURL, zip(itertools.repeat(urlSet), user, verboseFlag))" line saying "TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration". I don't want to iterate over this item, I just want to send the same value every time.

Comment: do all the processURL have the same user and verboseflag?

Comment: Both are specified on the command line. So, yes, but I can't hard code it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that urlset is an iterable, you should use

```
pool.starmap(processURL, zip(urlSet, repeat(user), repeat(verboseFlag)))
```

This is because you want to iterate over the urlset but have the same user and verboseFlag for each processURL instance(thus,repeat)

For reference you should take a look at [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)

The output of zip when iterated over, should look something like

```
[('www.google.com','user1',True),('www.goodle.uk','user1',True),]
```

for `pool.starmap` to make sense of it.